# Java 8 stream map custom function and convert it to Map

Tags: java-8, java-stream, collect

I have the following object:

```
public class Book {

    private Long id;
    private Long bookId;
    private String bookName;
    private String owner;
}
```

Represented from following table:
[image]

Basically, a book can be owned by multiple owners i.e. Owner "a" owns books 1 and 2.

I have a basic function that will when passed a book object, will give its owner(s) in a List.

```
private List<String> getBookToOwner(Book book) {
        List<String> a = new ArrayList<>();
        if (book.getOwner() != null && !book.getOwner().isEmpty()) {
            a.addAll(Arrays.asList(book.getOwner().split("/")));
        }
        return a;
}
```

I want to use that to apply to each book, retrieve their owners and create the following Map.

```
Map<String, List<Long>> ownerToBookMap;
```

Like this:

[image]

How do I use streams here?

```
//books is List<Book>
Map<String, List<Long>> ownerToBookMap = books.stream().map( 
// apply the above function to get its owners, flatten it and finally collect it to get the above Map object
// Need some help here..
);
```

Comment: Just a recommendation: don't include multiple values in a single column (the owner column in your case). So, to fix it I recommend that  you create a many-to-many relationship with the Owner table. In that case an intermediate mapping table will be created. check online for further details.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get the owner list from the book, then flatten the owners and map as pair of `bookId` and `owner` using `flatMap`. Then grouping by `owner` using `groupingBy` and collect the list of `bookId` of `owner`.

```
Map<String, List<Long>> ownerToBookMap = 
     books.stream()
          .flatMap(b -> getBookToOwner(b)
                         .stream()
                         .map(o -> new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<>(o, b.getBookId())))
          .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Map.Entry::getKey,
                     Collectors.mapping(Map.Entry::getValue, Collectors.toList())));
```

Comment: `Map.entry()` could be used starting from Java 9 instead of `SimpleEntry`

Answer (score 0):

I use `reduce` instead of `map`.

```
Map<String, List<Long>> ownerToBookMap = books.stream().reduce(
    HashMap::new,
    (acc,b) -> {
        getBookToOwner(b).stream().forEach( o -> {
            if (!acc.containsKey(o))
                acc.put(o, new ArrayList<Long>());
            acc.get(o).put(b.bookId);
        });
        return acc;
    }
).get();
```

Comment: @Abra Sorry, miss something.. I just updated the answer

Comment: I was getting some error when tried your first option. Later I used the above solution by @Rono which worked.

Answer (score 0):

Flatmap the owners into a single one, create entries with key as an *single* `owner` and value as a `bookId`. Then group the structure by the key (`owner`). Finally use `Collectors::mapping` to get the `List` of `bookId`s instead of the actual entries:

```
List<Book> books = ...

Map<String, List<Long>> booksByOwner = books.stream()
    .flatMap(book -> Arrays.stream(book.getOwner().split("/"))
             .map(owner -> new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<>(owner, book.getBookId())))
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
             AbstractMap.SimpleEntry::getKey, 
             Collectors.mapping(AbstractMap.SimpleEntry::getValue, Collectors.toList())));
```

Comment: So if a book has, for example, three owners, you create three, separate `Book` objects where each `Book` has precisely one owner. Then you can perform the `groupingBy` since each `Book` has only one owner. Isn't that expensive (in terms of time and resources)?

Comment: Actually, the short-lived objects are consumed by the garbage collector almost immediatelly. You can use `AbstractMap.SimpleEntry` instead.